# What are complexities of BigInteger.pow and BigInteger.isProbablePrime?

Tags: java, complexity-theory, biginteger

What are complexities of Java 7's methods [`pow`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow%28int%29) and [`isProbablePrime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime%28int%29) in the [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class?

I know that simple implementation of Rabin's test is of O(k(log(n))^3) complexity and that can be reduced by incorporating the [Schönhage-Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) for the fast multiplication of long integers.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code?  Or do you expect us to do it for you?

Comment: Have they improved the multiplication to sub-quadratic yet? Last time I checked it was still `O(n^2)`. All other major functions depend heavily on the speed of the multiplication.

Comment: I'd like to note that `pow()` and `isProbablyPrime()` are included since the very first version of `BigInteger` (according to the JavaDoc) and `BigInteger` was introduced in JDK 1.1! So that's by no means a new feature in Java 7.

Comment: @Stephen C: Unless the complexity is explicitly written in the source code, it is not easy to figure it out from just looking at the code.

Comment: @Mysticial - That doesn't address my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the standard algorithms, the complexities are:

```
pow()             : O( M(n * exponent) )
IsProbablePrime() : O( M(n) * n )
```

where:

- `n` is the number of digits in the operand.
- `exponent` is the exponent of the power function.
- `M(n)` is the run-time for an `n x n` digit multiplication. Which I believe is `O(n^2)` as of Java 6.

**Explanation for `pow()`:**

For an input operand of n-digits long raised to a power of `exp`, the output is roughly `n * exp` digits long. This is done by binary-powering algorithm where the operand is squared at each iteration. So the complexity becomes:

```
O( M(n) + M(2*n) + M(4*n) + ... M(n * exp/2) ) = O( M(n * exp) )
```

This is a geometric sum, so the sum becomes `O( M(n * exp) )`.

**Explanation for `IsProbablePrime()`:**

For a fixed number of Rabin-Miller iterations, each iteration has `O(n)` multiplications of size `n x n` digits. Therefore, the complexity becomes `O( n * M(n) )`.

Comment: Your answer for pow() is wrong, as it is computed via logarithms in the FPU. Nothing to do with multiplication or the number of digits. It would be wrong anyway for exponentation to an integral power, as there are much faster algorithms than just multiplying 'exponent' times. Your answer for isProbablePrime looks like mere guesswork.

Comment: @EJP: The BigInteger pow() function powers an integer to an integer power. There's no floating-point going on here. The result of powering an N-digit integer to an exponent of `m` will result in a number of roughly `N * m` digits long - which are done by large multiplications.

Comment: But not O(M(n*exponent)) multiplications. BigInteger.pow() uses a square-and-multiply algorithm as described in Knuth ACP vol II #4.6.3. The number of multiplications is O(sqrt(N)).

Comment: @EJP: `n*exponent` refers to the size of the operand. So `M(n * exponent)` means the time needed to multiply two numbers of size `n * exponent`. (not the # of multiplicatios - which is obviously `O(log(n))`) Don't forget that large multiplication is not constant. (That's why there's an `M()`)

Comment: So you don't have a factor in there for the number of multiplications at all?

Comment: @EJP: It's semi-geometric sum. Each of the subsequent multiplications doubles in size. So the sum ends up being a constant factor with respect to the largest multiplication. (the last one)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that it isn't specified and therefore subject to implementor's choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a look at the source, here it is: http://futureboy.us/temp/BigInteger.java.

Relevant material to your question here too: [What complexity are operations on Java 7's BigInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154117/what-complexity-are-operations-on-java-7s-biginteger)