# BigInteger most time optimized multiplication

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, biginteger, multiplication

Hi I want to multiply 2 big integer in a most timely optimized way. I am currently using karatsuba algorithm. Can anyone suggest more optimized way or algo to do it.

Thanks

```
public static BigInteger karatsuba(BigInteger x, BigInteger y) {

        // cutoff to brute force
        int N = Math.max(x.bitLength(), y.bitLength());
        System.out.println(N);
        if (N <= 2000) return x.multiply(y);                // optimize this parameter

        // number of bits divided by 2, rounded up
        N = (N / 2) + (N % 2);

        // x = a + 2^N b,   y = c + 2^N d
        BigInteger b = x.shiftRight(N);
        BigInteger a = x.subtract(b.shiftLeft(N));
        BigInteger d = y.shiftRight(N);
        BigInteger c = y.subtract(d.shiftLeft(N));

        // compute sub-expressions
        BigInteger ac    = karatsuba(a, c);
        BigInteger bd    = karatsuba(b, d);
        BigInteger abcd  = karatsuba(a.add(b), c.add(d));

        return ac.add(abcd.subtract(ac).subtract(bd).shiftLeft(N)).add(bd.shiftLeft(2*N));
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong with BigInteger.Multiply() ?

Comment: It's complexity is of order O(n^2). Karatsuba is approximately O(n^1.5). I want a more optimized one.

Comment: If you want speed then why not Toom-Cook ?

Comment: If they are huge, FFT-based multiplication could help. Should be something like O(n*log(n)).

Comment: yes I should use that. I read somewhere that it's complexity is O(n^1.4). Is it the best possible solution? Or there is a more optimized way?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze there can be upto 500 digits.

Comment: If the size isn't going to be bigger than 500 digits, then you won't need to go any higher than Karatsuba. Toom-Cook >=3 and FFT are only useful when you get into tens of thousands of digits.

Comment: Yeah, more details, as usual, here: [Multiplication algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm).

Comment: @Mysticial I am solving a spoj problem using karatsuba but it is giving me time limit exceeded. That is why I wanted the best way.

Comment: There's probably a way to solve the problem without solving *this* problem (fast bigint multiplication) then.

Comment: Like the Java SDK, you should use different methods for different sizes. For "small" bigintegers, you use the normal "schoolbook" multiplication. For bigger sizes, you use Karatsuba, For even larger sizes, you use Toom-Cook 3 way, or one of the other Toom-Cook versions, and for extremely huge bigintegers, you use FFT-based algorithms. These algorithms are all fast, but some only for very big integers. For smaller, their overhead is far too big. Even Karatsuba has too much overhead for small bigintegers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of BigInteger in jdk8 switches between the naive algorithm, The Toom-Cook algorithm, and Karatsuba depending on the size of the input to get excellent performance.

Comment: Here's the source, for the curious: https://github.com/dmlloyd/openjdk/blob/e7f494fc8/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L1558

Answer (score 4):

Complexity and actual speed are very different things in practice, because of the constant factors involved in the O notation. There is always a point where complexity prevails, but it may very well be out of the range (of input size) you are working with. The implementation details (level of optimization) of an algorithm also directly affect those constant factors.

My suggestion is to try a few different algorithms, preferably from a library that the authors already spent some effort optimizing, and actually measure and compare their speeds on your inputs.

Regarding SPOJ, don't forget the possibility that the main problem lies elsewhere (i.e. not in the multiplication speed of large integers).

Comment: Interestingly enough, the constant is dependent also upon the machine word size.  If you were dealing with raw bits, Karatsuba becomes advantageous much sooner, than if you can assume say 32 or 64-bit multiplications are O(1) and therefore the bit size will be higher.  Its also the details of memory allocation, copying and usage that are relevant as if you are not careful, the optimized algorithms tend to make the constant larger than is necessary.