# Java: Estimate available HW parallelism howto

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency, parallel-processing

I keep on with [fork/join optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191369/fork-join-optimization), *(or to be more precise with optimization of dividing input between threads)*. And faced the [next statement](http://shipilev.net/talks/javaday-Nov2013-streamstyle.pdf) (pg. 73):

Final parallelism speedup depends on:

- Number of source elements *(know value)*
- Cost of operation *(almost impossible to estimate)*
- ***Available HW parallelism (possible to estimate)***
- Number of concurrent clients *(we can somehow cope with it)*

***Question:*** *What does it mean: available HW parallelism? How to estimate available HW parallelism?*

Comment: Number of processors and number of cores per processor, assuming JVM is capable of taking advantage of them all.

Comment: [Runtime::availableProcessors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors--)

Comment: Dr. Heinz M. Kabutz did a [newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue220.html) on this recently.

Answer (score 2):

*hardware parallelism* denotes a broader concept and means how many computing or I/O resources you have available to do parallel operations.

For *computing resources*, this may be the available CPUs on your system. However that is only an exact measure, when your JVM is on a non virtualized, uniform multi core system.
In reality available processors may be shared in a virtual environment, may not have the same feature set, may be multi threaded, or share memory interfaces (NUMA).

For *I/O resources* it means the storage subsystem and how many requests it can do in parallel (e.g. the number of harddisks), plus, the I/O channel bandwidth.

For estimating your available "hardware parallelism" it is important to know which is the limiting factor for your workload. If I/O is not the problem, the task is called *CPU bound* or *I/O bound* otherwise. See my answer on [Choosing optimal number of Threads for parallel processing of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24157555/2594725). In this answer I also proposed the idea of using an adaptive algorithm to chose the number of threads.

Comment: can you explain `maxThreadCount - 1` and `new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(maxThreadCount * 2)` parameters please? How can I move those params to `ForkJoinPool`?

Comment: Just edited the answer in the linked question to make my intentions clear.

Comment: I have no experience `with ForkJoinPool`, but I think, by looking at the documentation, you can just use the available processor count. There are no "tricks" needed.

Comment: and let's not forget, with the introduction of lots of computing resources, we become cache-limited quickly