# Runtime of BigInteger operations?

Tags: java, runtime, big-o, biginteger

In Java, there is the [BigInteger class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html), which seems to be holding its contents internally as an array of ints. I'm imagining that additions/subtraction/bitShifting of two BigInteger numbers are O(N) "linear operations" as such. In fact, it seems that even multiplication and division are O(N log N)?

Without understanding the special large-number algorithms, would this be a sufficiently accurate general answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154117/what-complexity-are-operations-on-java-7s-biginteger

Comment: Note that N would usually denote the actual number stored in the BigInt, not its size in memory, which is denoted n = O(log N). All BigInt operations should at least be polynomial in n i.e. polylogarithmic in N.

Comment: The implementation in the BigInteger class has been gradually getting more sophisticated over the years, but for operands less than about 2500 bits an O(N\*\*2) algorithm is used. Operands larger than that are multiplied using the Karatsuba algorithm which is an O(N\*\*1.58) algorithm. Still more sophisticated algorithms are used as the operands get really large.